# What adapter do I need to connect the headphone to a laptop and a smartphone?

Tags: laptop, audio, compatibility, audio-adapters

A friend of mine has [a Dell Vostro 3568 laptop](https://www.amazon.in/3581-15-6-inch-i3-7020U-Windows-Graphics/dp/B07XZHHMVV/ref=pd_aw_sbs_147_4/257-2749132-3964649?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07XZHHMVV&pd_rd_r=1f7f87c6-7277-4e17-9b9a-df30116bed45&pd_rd_w=UOM5a&pd_rd_wg=fRvsp&pf_rd_p=695cf2c3-c92f-40a6-82c6-fff7783abc65&pf_rd_r=65P8Y6M52FYD9NV95BHK&psc=1&refRID=65P8Y6M52FYD9NV95BHK). Here are the screenshots of `msinfo32` command: [msinfo32 output1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FldsUSjDNyJGkLbhXO5B_7r2tyYCofvR), [msinfo32 output2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uAhIgi1-m1rffqqMQ92H-1eAPXQGK0Xj/view?usp=sharing).

The audio port looks like this: [audio part screenshot1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18KNzfLL4R_sPIYIj3Uc2KS26RnALgdPW), [audio part screenshot2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ILquCn9VM9JvAjLIcwHLCpzDW3eAtf1g).

He wants is a converter which can be used so that the same headphone can be used in Android mobile phone and laptop.

If it is visible in the screenshot then you see inside the hole in audio port there is one pin deep inside which is coming out.
We are looking for an adaptor which can be used with an android smartphone as well and the laptop also.
What sort of adapter is needed for it?

Comment: Have you *tried* using some headphones with that laptop and an android phone? The laptop has a standard 3.5mm audio jack, that connection has been used for *almost* every pair of headphones, laptop, or phone. Some phones no longer have a 3.5mm audio jack but there would be an adapter for the *phone*, not the laptop, to add a 3.5mm jack. Some headphones have a larger audio jack that would need an adapter to make it smaller. We need more information about the phone and the headphones you are trying to use in order to answer your question.